# Формат ввода текста в EditText по аналогии с таймером в стандартном приложении "Часы"

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

Нужно сделать ввод десятичной дроби следующим образом:
в самом начале в поле ввода отображается **0.000**, при вводе цифр получается следующее

```
ввели "3" -> 0.003     
ввели "1" -> 0.031  
ввели "6" -> 0.316  
ввели "9" -> 3.169  
ввели "0" - > 31.690 и т.д.
```

Да, можно свой велосипед, но хотелось бы найти красивое решение. Даже гуглить не знаю как.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher());

class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        boolean mEditing;

        public NumberTextWatcher() {
            mEditing = false;
        }

        public synchronized void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!mEditing) {
                mEditing = true;
                // Strip symbols
                String digits = s.toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");
                NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
                nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
                try {
                    String formatted = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(digits) / 1000);
                    s.replace(0, s.length(), formatted);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    s.clear();
                }
                mEditing = false;
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    }
```